# Have Images appear from database

Tags: php, mysql, prettyphoto

So I have a `images` table in my database, with the following 4 columns:

```
pgname | id | imageurl | username
```

A user is able to save images to the table, adding the users pagename as pgname, autoincremented id, the url of the image as imageurl, and the persons username.

Im using the [prettyphoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) jquery gallery to return the images.

Im trying to get the url of the images associated with the users pgname to appear in the hyperlink of my div, with the following code:

```
$imagesquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE `pgname` = '$pgname'") or die(mysqli_error());
        while ($returnImages = mysql_fetch_assoc($imagesquery))  {
        $img = array($returnImages['imageurl']);
        }

        foreach ($img as $imageData) {
        echo'<div id="imageslide"><a href="'.$imageData.'" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><img style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" src="'.$imageData.'" alt=""/></a></div>';
        }
```

What i get is an empty box for every imageurl there is in the table. 
Is there any way to make the images appear? Because what im trying to do is make multiple images inside of one prettyphoto gallery.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Echo what? Your code doesn't print anything as-is.

Comment: mysql_fetch returns a single ROW of data. You're treating it as if it returns all of the rows. Either build an array of data, or move your echo into the fetch loop.

Comment: @Xyon i just edited the code.

Comment: @MarcB how would i echo out the database rows as an array, then echo out each individual result in its own <a href> ?

Answer (score 0):

As Marc said, you have to build array of data or move your echo into the fetch loop, try the following

```
$imagesquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE `pgname` = '$pgname'") or die(mysqli_error());
while ($returnImages = mysql_fetch_assoc($imagesquery))  {
       echo'<div id="imageslide"><a href="'.$returnImages['imageurl'].'" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><img style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" src="'.$returnImages['imageurl'].'" alt=""/>'.$returnImages['pgname'].'</a></div>';
}
```

Please don't use mysql_* function as it's deprecated by php.net, you can use mysqli_* OR PDO.

Answer (score 0):

I might try something more like this:

```
$imagesQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE `pgname` = '$pgname'") or die(mysqli_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($imagesQuery))  {
    echo '<div id="imageslide"><a href="'.$row['imageurl'].'" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><img style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" src="'.$row['imageurl'].'" alt=""/></a></div>';
}
```

Also, I think it's important to give some thought to the way you name things. Why would you use the name `$imageData` for something that's really a URL? Why give the name `$img` to something that's really an array? And if you're going to use camelCase, use camelCase everywhere, i.e. `imagesQuery` and `imageUrl` (or `imageURL`) instead of `imagesquery` and `imageurl`. If you name things as clearly as you can, everything else will be easier and faster.

Sorry if that sounds like a criticism. I'm not trying to be harsh; I mean what I say as a friendly tip.

Comment: I tried it, its giving me the same issue. I have 2 paginations on the screen, because I have 2 tables, one table for the users info, and another table for the users images.

Comment: Before trying to get prettyPhoto involved, see if you can simply print a list of all the image URLs on a page. Otherwise you won't know if the problem is with your PHP/SQL or your JavaScript.